# Batch to skip delimiter only to a certain moment

Tags: batch-file, command-line, registry, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to get my current username by registry using command line. But my username has two words between a space. Ex.: "Cat Dog". Well, if i use a space as delimiter, it only prints 'Cat', if i put `tokens=3` it prints also the same because there's a space between these two words.

I'm doing it to use in many computers, so i can't determine the exactly username of each one. How can i delimiter from the first word of the token number `3` until the end not mattering how much spaces it has ?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\1 /v LoggedOnUser') do (
set "user=%%a")
set "user=%user:.\=%"
echo %user%
pause
```

Comment: Use `tokens=2*` and set `user` to `%%b`. You also need "*." in the `set`, not `.\`

Comment: Make that "*\" not ".\"

Comment: @Magoo awsome. Thank you. Should i delet this question or not?

Comment: I'd leave it, personally. No doubt you're not the only one with a similar question - and that's what SO is all about. If you use `tokens` then you can use a comma-separated list of token numbers, or a range *start*-*finish* or `*`. The tokens are then applied to the metavariable and the next, etc. alphabetically. `*` means `the rest of the line`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you couldn't use the whoami command? For example:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('whoami') do set "user=%%g"
```

Comment: I'm worried if the system is running the file, so i can't get the real current user

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a system variable %username% in the environment

```
echo %username%
```